# How to run Nginx with a custom config inside Docker?

Tags: nginx, docker

Nginx config has a `daemon off;` directive set in `/root/nginx.conf`.

I am trying to run it under docker using this command:

```
sudo docker run --name nginx-redirect -p 3128:3128 -v /root/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf:ro -d nginx
```

but nothing happens (except Docker output of container ID; I think it should means that all is ok), and `netstat -tulpn` shows no `docker/nginx` container and no `3128` port, where I'm wrong?

`/root/nginx.conf`:

```
user www-data;
worker_processes auto;
pid /run/nginx.pid;
daemon off;

events {
  worker_connections 768;
}

http {
  server {
    listen 3128;
    location / {
      proxy_pass http://example.com;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The nginx container by default runs with `daemon off;` and you can verify that from the Dockerfile

```
FROM debian:jessie

MAINTAINER NGINX Docker Maintainers "docker-maint@nginx.com"

ENV NGINX_VERSION 1.10.2-1~jessie

RUN apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://pgp.mit.edu:80 --recv-keys 573BFD6B3D8FBC641079A6ABABF5BD827BD9BF62 \
    && echo "deb http://nginx.org/packages/debian/ jessie nginx" >> /etc/apt/sources.list \
    && apt-get update \
    && apt-get install --no-install-recommends --no-install-suggests -y \
                        ca-certificates \
                        nginx=${NGINX_VERSION} \
                        nginx-module-xslt \
                        nginx-module-geoip \
                        nginx-module-image-filter \
                        nginx-module-perl \
                        nginx-module-njs \
                        gettext-base \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# forward request and error logs to docker log collector
RUN ln -sf /dev/stdout /var/log/nginx/access.log \
    && ln -sf /dev/stderr /var/log/nginx/error.log

EXPOSE 80 443

CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

[Nginx Dockerfile](https://github.com/nginxinc/docker-nginx/blob/25a3fc7343c6916fce1fba32caa1e8de8409d79f/stable/jessie/Dockerfile)

So you need to remove the daemon directive from your nginx file run the container and it should work fine.